# admin-on-rest Show component with specified id on custom page

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest in my React app and wonder how is possible to make a custom page containing Show (or another detail component) with specified resource Id (for example: I want my app to fetch only resource with id = 1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is canonical or the intended way to do things but you can supply both basePath and record as props to the ShowButton and EditButton components.

You can use this to redirect your user basically anywhere.

It should be possible (using some switch case or dependent input addon) to also add these props to the ListButton in the Show and Edit view and redirect your user back to the originating ListView.

Here is documentation to supply actions to the List view.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#actions